# calling destructor of reference?

Tags: c++

Here is my example code

```
    class king
{
public:
    king(int q)
        :queen(q)
    {
    }

    ~king()
    {
        cout << "king's destructor." << endl;
    }

    void operator= (const king &k)
    {
        cout << "king's copy constructor." << endl;
        queen = k.queen;
    }

private:
    int queen;
};

void refFunc0(king &k)
{
    king &kk = k;
}

void refFunc1(king &k)
{
    king kk = k;
}

void main()
{
    int qqq0 = 55;

    king kkk0(qqq0);
    refFunc0(kkk0);

    cout << qqq0 << endl;

    int qqq1 = 66;
    king kkk1(qqq1);
    refFunc1(kkk1);

    cout << qqq1 << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

can anyone help explain what happened in above code?
I mean if I pass a reference into a function, will the reference variable call destructor then destroy the original variable passed into the function as reference?

Comment: That's not a copy constructor, that's a copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 9):

References are not objects, they just *refer* to an object. Binding a reference to an object has no effect on the object lifetime (other than possibly extending it if the reference is `const` and the object is a temporary, but it surely won't reduce the lifetime)

Answer (score 1):

This function :

```
void refFunc1(king &k)
{
    king kk = k;
}
```

is creating `king`'s copy. The destructor is called on the copied object. Then again, it is called two more times on the `king` objects in the main().

Answer (score 1):

refFunc0 does absolutely nothing. A reference is simply another name of an object.
refFunc1 will create a copy of king in kk and then will destroy kk when the function ends.
kkk0 and kkk1 will be destroyed when 'main' ends.